# How to check adoc file type when uploading a file

Tags: html, typescript, file-upload

I'm trying to upload files only with allowed extensions, for example jpg, png and so on. I also have to allow uploading adoc files.

`<input type="file" multiple (change)="onFileSelected($event)"/>`

I am using `file.type` to check the type of file.

```
onFileSelected(event) {
  Array.from(event.target.files).forEach(file => {
    if (Object.values(AttachmentTypeEnum).includes(file.type)) {
      this.upload(file);
    }
  });
}
```

The problem is that uploaded adoc file's `file.type` is empty. Is there a way to check for adoc files?

Comment: Does adding accept property  <input type="file" multiple accept=".adoc"> help?

Comment: @Ava_Katushka, yes, that helps. But user still can choose "All Files" and upload anything...